# What Facebook permission/scope is required for /{user-id}/links Graph API endpoint?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This endpoint is mentioned in the [/{user-id}/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed) docs, along with:

- /{user-id}/posts
- /{user-id}/statuses
- /{user-id}/tagged

These do not seem to be documented anywhere else.  The docs state that read_stream permission is required, but Facebook have recently become massively reluctant to grant this to apps.

However, /{user-id}/statues also seems to be accessible if users grant user_status permission, so I wondered if there is an equivalent way to get /{user-id}/links **without read_stream**?

Comment: 'read_stream', but in latest api version i believe he is returning and empty array always..

Comment: @Sunand: this is true, but my real question is "if there is an equivalent way to get /{user-id}/links without read_stream?"

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/

> ```
> Any valid access token is required to view public links.
> A user access token with read_stream permission is required.
> Only posts whose authors have also granted read_stream permission to the app will be shown.
> ```

I don´t think it´s possible without `read_stream`, and you will definitely not get it approved.